# Determinant of Union Jack matrix without Scottish diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $n \ge 1$ be an integer , and let $A_n$ be the matrix in $M_{2n-1}\mathbb(F)$ with entries $(a_{ij})$ where $a_{ij}=1 $ if $i+j=2n$  or $i=n$ or $j=n,$ and $a_{ij}=0$ otherwise . Find det$(A_n)$

***my idea:***

for $n=4$ the matrix of the form from the given data

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 &  &  & 1 &  &  &1 \\ 
 &  &  &  1&  &  1& \\ 
 &  &  &  1& 1 &  & \\ 
 1&1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1  &1 \\ 
 &  &  1&  1&  &  & \\ 
 &  1&  &  1&  &  & \\ 
 1&  &  &1  &  &  & 
\end{bmatrix}$$

How to find genearl formula for determent :

Comment: I am getting $(-1)^{n+1} (2n-1)$

Comment: @KingTut..can you explain plz

Comment: (1/2)@KingTut: for $n = 2$ I get a determinant equal to $1$. I think you can set up some inductive step for $n \geq 3$ or $4$ as follows: Expand the first row. There are only two determinants to compute in this expansion: the determinant you get from entry $(1,n)$ should be the determinant of a permutation matrix. The one you get from entry $(1, 2n-1)$ resembles the original matrix, but skewed. To compute this last determinant, expand the last row. The determinant you obtain from entry $(2n-1-1,1)$ is the original matrix if I am correct. The other determinant should again be the determinant of

Comment: (2/2) a permutation matrix. The reason you can only use induction for $n \geq 3$ is clear, since we use the induction hypothesis on $n-2$ instead of $n-1$ when proving the case of $n$. **I am not suer if this will give you the right answer, but this is how I would proceed...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the mirror image of the matrix, so you get a factor $(-1)^{n-1}$. Now the mirror image is
$$
I
+\pmatrix{
&&&1\\ 
&&&\vdots\\ 
&&&1\\ 
1&\cdots&1&0&1&\cdots&1\\
&&&1\\ 
&&&\vdots\\ 
&&&1}=I+B\quad \text{(say)}.
$$
Clearly, the matrix $B$ has rank $2$ and $(1,\ldots,1,\pm\sqrt{2n-2},1,\ldots,1)^T$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\pm\sqrt{2n-2}$. Hence $\det A=(-1)^{n-1}(1+\sqrt{2n-2})(1-\sqrt{2n-2})=(-1)^n(2n-3)$.

**Edit.** Alternatively, subtract the middle row by the sum of all other rows. Then subtract the middle column by the sum of all other columns. What remains is a matrix with $(1,\ldots,1,-(2n-3),1,\ldots,1)$ on its anti-diagonal and zeroes elsewhere. Therefore $\det(A)=-(2n-3)\times(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^n(2n-3)$.

Comment: I do not really understand how you computed the determinant of $A$, could you explain how this determinant is linked with the eigenvalues of $B$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Student If $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ are the eigenvalues of $B$, then $1+b_1,\ldots,1+b_n$ are the eigenvalues of $I+B$.

Comment: Very stupid question from my part, should have thought some more about this. Thank you for your quick answer!